# Ubuntu 17.04 wifi unstable

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my new Asus R518UQ-RH74T.
If I use a wired network, it all works great. The problem is when I connect to a wifi network.
It works for a while, and then turns slow to the point I can't even open google.com

I've been googling for an answer and tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905283/wifi-issue-with-ubuntu-17-04), but no success.
I've seen there were problems on the past with my wifi adapter, but [seems to be compatible since kernel version 4.1](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html)).

Anyways, I'm hoping someone can help me get this to work.
This is the result for `lspci -vv -s 03:00.0`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 282
Region 0: Memory at ef100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798644/unstable-wifi-with-intel-8260-808624f3-rev-3a-on-ubuntu-16-04-runnung-on-le/798697#798697) steps, and it seems to work now!
Hope someone finds this useful!

---

Actually, it was still failing 'cause I've installed the wrong drivers.
When I installed [this one](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.164.1_all.deb), seems to be working fine (Hope this is it).
Anyway, if you check [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware) (Version 1.164.1), you'll see this very same issue listed in the changelog.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.