# 16.04 drops wireless activity every few minutes

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I can connect to and use wireless access points.  After several minutes, however, I can no longer use them.  The task bar applet shows a connection, but I can't send or receive data.  Using `service network-manager restart` fixes the problem, but only temporarily, and I'm getting very tired of having to do it constantly.

I've read page after page on this site and elsewhere of lists of commands to run.  Here's a summary of the information I've found as a result:

```
logical name: wlp4s0
driver=iwlwifi
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

I'm on a Lenovo ThinkPad T560.

`iwconfig` indicates Power Management is on.

`rfkill` indicates nothing is blocked, hard or soft

I've blocked IPv6 by adding

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

to the `/etc/sysctl.conf` config file and rebooting, but that did nothing.

For the present, I'm more interested in learning how to figure out what the problem is than in fixing it.  How do I find out what's going wrong?

**Info Edit 1:** When this happens, I suddenly cannot load web pages.  I cannot ping my default gateway (100% packet loss), and I cannot ping sites by name ("unknown host").

**Info Edit 2:** I tried turning Power Management off using `$ sudo iwconfig <wlan0> power off`.  The problem recurred, even as I confirmed using `iwconfig` that Power Management remained off.  The problem also happens regardless of whether I'm on battery or cable power.

When the disconnection happens, there is little change in the output of `iwconfig`.  In particular, these parameters stay nearly constant:

```
Bit-rate=866.7 Mb/s
Tx-Power=22 dBm
Link Quality=70/70
Signal level=-40 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0
Rx invalid crypt:0
Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0
```

`Access Point` remains a constant, valid MAC address throughout.  The only output that changes is `Invalid misc`, which increases in count noticeably and continuously after the disconnection.

**Meta Edit:** Someone has linked to a similar question at [Unstable wifi with intel 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a) on Ubuntu 16.04 running on Lenovo P50](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798644).  That user seems to have a more severe problem than I do.  I don't lose sight of networks or have the applet icon change, I just stop being able to send and receive internet data, as if the connection is being throttled down to nothing.

In any event, I emphasize that **there is no resolution or accepted answer on that question**, and no activity in nearly a year.  The existence of this similar question does not help me solve my problem.

Comment: Can you clarify "can't send or receive data" - can you ping your default gateway by IP address? can you ping a web address by name?  

It could be that you are still connected but dns has got messed up.  

If it's not that, what is the output of `iwconfig`? Do you see errors and/or a drop in quality?

Comment: Another thought: try turning power management **off**. 

`sudo iwconfig _ifname_ power off`

This helps some people. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on for example.

Comment: @Joe P - I see recommendations to turn power management off, but not much discussion of what that means.  "Power management" sounds like something I might want - what are the consequences of turning it off?  If that's the problem, is there another way to fix it without losing the benefits?

Comment: @PiotrChernin - power management attempts to conserve power (a good thing for battery life etc) by reducing transmit power or actually turning it off, when there's no traffic. But some devices and access points seem to lose connection in these conditions, or not be able to resume sufficient power (not a good thing).

Comment: @Joe P - edited my question.  I can't ping anything.  I don't see any obvious error in the output of iwconfig - what aspect of it would indicate an error or drop in quality?

Comment: Have you tried turning power management off and running for a while? This may avoid 'bugs' in the driver and/or access point.

Comment: Regarding iwconfig, the values are specific to the driver - the command just reports them - so I haven't found general guidance. Look at 'Link Quality' from time to time. Look at the last line, tx excessive retries and invalid misc and see if they are increasing significantly (it's OK to have some). And if any of the 'Rx invalid ...' values are above 0 it might indicate a problem.

Comment: Plus ... if iwconfig shows 'Access point: Not-associated' then your wifi is disconnected!

Comment: What counts with these things is the hardware - that's why the question is linked - it's the chipset. Support tends to improve over time which likely explains why your problem is less severe. Please try the steps suggested there and edit your question with the results.

Comment: @Zanna, other interested persons - in order to attempt the answer given there, I've had to post a [secondary question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921586/how-do-i-change-which-firmware-is-used-for-my-wireless-card).  If you can help me out with that, it will speed things up here.