# 18.04 Bluetooth works for first 2 minutes then stops.

Tags: bluetooth, 18.04

This is a fresh install of 18.04 on my Thinkpad T460p with intel 9260 wifi/bluetooth card.

Everything works for the fist 2 minutes, the bluetooth disappears. It appears permanently off (cannot set to on) until I reboot when the same happens.

This is my journalctl -b | grep bluetooth

```
enter code here
May 03 22:05:19 weywot kernel: thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked  
May 03 22:05:20 weywot NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1525381520.5047] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
May 03 22:05:20 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
May 03 22:05:20 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: Starting SDP server
May 03 22:05:20 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
May 03 22:05:20 weywot NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1525381520.9215] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
May 03 22:05:20 weywot NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1525381520.9279] bluez5: NAP: added interface 8C:A9:82:FD:1E:F6
May 03 22:05:21 weywot /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.153 blueY: 0.061   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
May 03 22:05:23 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
May 03 22:05:23 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 22:05:38 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: bt_uhid_send: Invalid argument (22)
May 03 21:08:25 weywot systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
May 03 21:08:25 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
May 03 21:08:25 weywot bluetoothd[1112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.36 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
May 03 21:08:25 weywot NetworkManager[993]: <info>  [1525378105.8666] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 8C:A9:82:FD:1E:F6
May 03 21:08:25 weywot dbus-daemon[965]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.36" (uid=1000 pid=1320 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.21" (uid=0 pid=1112 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
May 03 21:08:25 weywot dbus-daemon[965]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.36" (uid=1000 pid=1320 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.21" (uid=0 pid=1112 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
May 03 21:08:25 weywot dbus-daemon[965]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.36" (uid=1000 pid=1320 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.21" (uid=0 pid=1112 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
May 03 21:08:25 weywot dbus-daemon[965]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.36" (uid=1000 pid=1320 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1.Error.NotImplemented" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.21" (uid=0 pid=1112 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
```

Clearly something's wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From this answer: [(16.04.2) Wireless Periodically Stops Working (Intel 8260)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966118/16-04-2-wireless-periodically-stops-working-intel-8260), you can try this:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 11n_disable=8
```

Comment: Thank you. Not much change. I think the whole intel9260 is not well supported. I ran 17.10 with 4.15 mainline and everything worked, and had hoped that with 18.04 I would not need to be on mainline. However the 9260 on 5GHz is only 0.5MB/s fast. On 4.16 it goes full speed. But the bluetooth problem persists.

Comment: My Bluetooth mouse finally stopped lagging. Thanks!